# Expand all Tables in Power BI XML imprt

Tags: xml, powerbi, powerquery

I have a folder with a (large) number of XML files that all have the same structure. I can import the folder in Power BI and use the combine feature to combine them into one table. However, all columns contain further nested tables. For some reason it won't let me embed images, but [here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwbxD.jpg).
I can manually expand the tables but there are so many nested tables that this would take an eternity.

I did find [this](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2014/05/21/expanding-all-columns-in-a-table-in-power-query/) blogpost that seems to get referenced a lot, but I was unable to get the code there to work, after running the function the table still looks exactly the same.

I'm new to Power BI so excuse me if this is a silly question, but maybe I'm just missing something simple.

EDIT: This is what the table query looks like currently:
[table query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPqQZ.png)

I basically just imported it and then I tried manually expanding one column to see if that would change anything, but it doesn't.

EDIT2: This is what the ExpandAll function looks like. The name should be correct:
[ExpandAll function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlhhO.png)
It also takes forever to run, even though right now I'm only using a couple of my files in a test database. I have found [this](https://gist.github.com/baldwicc/4823ab4c34e37b17b8501d3c1f3a59a4) fork of it that finishes faster, but it still doesn't seem to do anything (nothing gets expanded).

Answer (score 0):

Chris's code from 
https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2014/05/21/expanding-all-columns-in-a-table-in-power-query/  
should work fine for you

First step, create a query with that code

```
let Source = (TableToExpand as table, optional ColumnNumber as number) =>
//https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2014/05/21/expanding-all-columns-in-a-table-in-power-query/
let ActualColumnNumber = if (ColumnNumber=null) then 0 else ColumnNumber,
 ColumnName = Table.ColumnNames(TableToExpand){ActualColumnNumber},
 ColumnContents = Table.Column(TableToExpand, ColumnName),
 ColumnsToExpand = List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(ColumnContents, each if _ is table then Table.ColumnNames(_) else {}))),
 NewColumnNames = List.Transform(ColumnsToExpand, each ColumnName & "." & _),
 CanExpandCurrentColumn = List.Count(ColumnsToExpand)>0,
 ExpandedTable = if CanExpandCurrentColumn then Table.ExpandTableColumn(TableToExpand, ColumnName, ColumnsToExpand, NewColumnNames) else TableToExpand,
 NextColumnNumber = if CanExpandCurrentColumn then ActualColumnNumber else ActualColumnNumber+1,
 OutputTable = if NextColumnNumber>(Table.ColumnCount(ExpandedTable)-1) then ExpandedTable else ExpandAll(ExpandedTable, NextColumnNumber)
in OutputTable
in Source
```

name the query/function **ExpandAll** and save and load it. The name here matters, because the function is self referencing, so you'd have to change the function code as well if you used a different name

Go to the query with your table in it and call the function as the final step

```
Output = ExpandAll(#"TheNameofMyPriorStepGoesHere")
in Output
```

**EDIT**

for example, in home..advanced editor... your existing query is similar to:

```
...
#"something"= Table.AddColumn(xxxxxxxx),
#"something2"= Table.AddColumn(#"something",xxxxxxxx)
in #"something2"
```

so, remove the last row, add a comma to end of row, then add two rows as below:

```
...
#"something"= Table.AddColumn(xxxxxxxx),
#"something2"= Table.AddColumn(#"something",xxxxxxxx), //<<<added comma
Output = ExpandAll(#"something2")
in Output
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Could you possibly elaborate or show a screenshot of where to put the function call of the ExpandAll query in my table? I believe that's the point where I'm stuck.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately, when I do it as you described I get an error saying that a cyclic reference was detected.

Comment: Without you posting your code, we have no idea how to help further, as you seem to be doing something wrong. Best of luck

Comment: I have posted a screenshot of my table query, in case there's anything obvious in there.

Comment: and whats the function look like, including the name for it

Comment: I've added the screenshot of the ExpandAll function. I've also changed the language of the code in the screenshots to English for convenience.

Comment: First glance, seems like it should work. Does it work without the final function call?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but it doesn't matter what step I call the function from. Of course, if I don't call the ExpandAll function, nothing happens and I just get my table with nothing expanded like in the 1st example. If I call Chris's code at any point, the cyclic reference error mentioned above comes up after running for a really long time. Baldwicc's fork of the code from my link finishes in a second or so, but doesn't expand anything and just returns the same table (1st example). The same behavior occurs when I select the tables in the GUI dropdown menu inside the funtions.

Comment: I can't tell, sorry