# Power Query to open XML file formatted as Excel would open it

Tags: excel, xml, powerbi, xml-parsing, powerquery

I have an XML file generated by EasyPower (electrical software).  If I open the file in Excel it comes up as a series of formatted sheets like the image below.  It appears this way without any prompts or dialogs.

[image]

I’m creating a Power Query routine that can extract the data from the sheets.  Unfortunately when I use the Power Query wizard to select the XML file as a source, it doesn’t see the data as sheets, but rather a table with columns of Tables, seemingly an infinite number of levels deep.  Digging through them I’m unable to clearly see the data.  This is not a very good approach.

[image]

A work-around is for me to manually open the XML file with Excel and save it as XLSX, then it’s easy to work with the data in Power Query.  I know a VBA script could be used to this but my question is, is there a way for Power Query to open an XML file and interpret the layout the same way that Excel does?  This way would allow my script to also work within Power BI.

Edit:  A sample file has been requested.  This link will provide a very simple example containing two worksheets when opened in Excel. [EasyPower_Test_Schedule.xml](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZJUhfVZm9cHsSB6z8BWL5B76kkEb8jssjdX)

Comment: Try to expand all tables in the powerquery import and see what that gets you

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74053591/expand-all-tables-in-power-bi-xml-imprt/74055238#74055238

Comment: You need to supply a sample file in order to troubleshoot.

Comment: I'm not able to share the file as it contains proprietary information.

Comment: @horseyride, I implemented a function from your link to expand all and it ran for a long time.  It either failed with a memory error or crashed Excel.

Comment: Sorry, the link works fine for most uses, and it is impossible to troubleshoot with the level of detail you have provided.  As @David said, you need a sample file to share.  If it has proprietary info, then change some numbers or data to make it non proprietary

Comment: I don't have access to the software that generates the file.  The file is 30 megabytes and too tedious to edit.  I'll see if I can get a sample that is not proprietary.

Comment: I have included a link to a sample file at the bottom of my question.  Does this get you any further?